# On the form of injective function $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ such that $\|u\|:=f^{-1}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^nf(|u_i|)\Big)$ is a norm

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ be injective such that on $\mathbb R^n , n>1)$ , $\|u\|:=f^{-1}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^nf(|u_i|)\Big)$ , where $u=(u_1,u_,\ldots,u_n)$ , defines a norm ; then is it true that for some $p\ge1$ , $f(x)=cx^p , \forall x \in \mathbb R^+$ ?

Comment: Yes, but you should assume $n\ge 2$ and allow $f(x)=cx^p$. Consider the implication of the identity $f^{-1}(2f(t)) = ct$, $t\ge 0$.